# Starting n number of threads from a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

So basically, I've this function th() which counts till certain number and then prints "done".
I'd want to start n number of such threads at the same time, running simultaneously.
So I wrote:

```
thread_num = 3 #here n is 3, but I'd normally want something way higher

thrds = []

i = 0
while i < thread_num:
    thr = Thread(target=th, args=())
    thrds.append(thr)
    i += 1
    print("thread", str(i), "added")

for t in thrds:
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

I'd want all the threads to print "done" at the same time, but they have a noticeable lag in between of them. They print "thread i started" at seemingly the same time, but print "done" with quite a bit of time lag.
Why is this happening?

Edit: Since someone asked me to add th() function as well, here it is:

```
def th():
    v = 0
    num = 10**7

    while v < num:
        v += 1
    print("done")
```

Comment: Can you post your `th` function?

Answer (score 1):

Because you start and join each thread sequentially, one thread will run to completion before the next even starts. You'd be better off running a thread pool which is a more comprehensive implementation that handles multiple issues in multithreading.

Because of memory management and object reference count issues, python only lets a single thread execute byte code at a time. Periodically, each thread will release and reacquire the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) to let other threads run. Exactly which thread runs at any given time is up to the operating system and you may find one gets more slices than another, causing staggered results.

To get them all to print "done" at the same time, you could use a control structure like a barrier for threads to wait until all are done. With a barrier, all threads must call `wait` before any can continue.

```
thread_num = 3 #here n is 3, but I'd normally want something way higher
wait_done = threading.Barrier(thread_num)

def th(waiter):
    x = 1 # to what you want
    waiter.wait()
    print("done")

thrds = []

i = 0
while i < thread_num:
    thr = Thread(target=th, args=(wait_done,))
    thrds.append(thr)
    i += 1
    print("thread", str(i), "added")

for t in thrds:
    t.start()
for t in thrds:
    t.join()
```

Comment: I think this will deadlock, because `t.join()` is inside the for loop along with `t.start()`.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay - didn't notice that - it would explain the delayed dones.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to start all the threads, then join all the threads in separate `for` loops; otherwise, each thread starts but runs to completion due to `join` before starting another thread.

```
for t in thrds:  # start all the threads
    t.start()
for t in thrds:  # wait for all threads to finish
    t.join()
```

If you only have a simple counting thread, you may need to add some short sleep to actually see the threads output intermingle as they may still run fast enough to complete before another thread starts.